# Find position in JSON object when importing into Google Sheets using split index import

Tags: arrays, json, google-sheets, getjson

I'm using this function in Google Sheets to import JSON object

```
=SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA(ʺURLS ʺ), 1, 3), ʺ:ʺ)
```

The structure of the object is like this

```
 {
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "Jack" : "Damery",
        "Height" : 0.00000919,
        "Low" : 0.00000820,
        "D" : 74339.61396015

    }, {
        "Jack" : "Big Dog",
        "Height" : 0.00000072,
        "Low" : 0.00000001,
        "D" : 166340678.42280999    
    }
]
```

}

How can I find the location of "Jack" and return it's value? Or how can I manage this object better in Sheets? My current formula returns

```
result:[ "Jack":"Damery"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is expected ouput? Can you share the format?

Comment: Expected output is the value of "Jack", or any of the fields in the "result" array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function `importdata` is for importing CSV data, not JSON. To actually convert an external JSON file to a format suitable for Sheets, one usually needs a script. But the specific task can be done with a regular expression:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, """Jack"" : ""([^""]*)""")
```

Apart from escaping, this regular expression is `"Jack" : "([^"]*)"` so it would return "Damery" in your example.